# c socket file transfer, server does not open existing file

Tags: c, linux, sockets, gcc

I am writing simple client-server program. Essentially I am following example from "Linux Network Programming" book. This is simple TCP server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SERVERPORT 8888
#define MAXBUF 1024
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int socket1, socket2;
    int addrlen;
    struct sockaddr_in fServer, fClient;
    int status;
    socket1=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socket1==-1)
    {
        printf("Could not create the socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fServer.sin_family=AF_INET;
    fServer.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    fServer.sin_port= htons(SERVERPORT);
    status=bind(socket1, (struct sockaddr*) &fServer,
                         sizeof(fServer));
    if(status==-1)
    {
          printf("could not bind the socket\n");
          exit(1);
    }
    else printf("socket is created\n");
    status=listen(socket1, 5);
    if(status==-1)
    {
         printf("could not listen socket\n");
         exit(1);
    }
    else printf("socket is waiting for connection\n");
    for(;;)
    {
         int fd;
         int i, readCounter, writeCounter;
         char* bufptr;
         char buf[MAXBUF];
         char filename[MAXBUF];
         addrlen=sizeof(fClient);
         socket2=accept(socket1, (struct sockaddr*) &fClient, &addrlen);
         if(socket2==-1)
         {
                printf("could not accept connection\n");
                exit(1);
         }
         else printf("connection established, waiting for the file name\n");
         i=0;
         if((readCounter=read(socket2, filename, MAXBUF))>0)
                i+=readCounter;
         filename[i+1]='\0';
         printf("reading from the file\n");
         fd=open(filename, O_RDONLY);
         if(fd==-1)
         {
                printf("could not open the file\n");
                perror(" error is detected: ");
                close(socket2);
                continue;
         }
         else printf("file name is recieved, started copying\n");
         readCounter=0;
         while((readCounter=read(fd, buf, MAXBUF))>0)
         {
                writeCounter=0;
                bufptr=buf;
                while(writeCounter<readCounter)
                {
                       readCounter-=writeCounter;
                       bufptr+=writeCounter;
                       writeCounter=write(socket2, bufptr, readCounter);
                       if(writeCounter==-1)
                       {
                             printf("could not write the file to client\n");
                             close(socket2);
                             continue;
                       }
                }
          }
          close(fd);
          close(socket2);
      }
      close(socket1);
      return 0;
}
```

This code is for client.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SERVERPORT 8888
#define MAXBUF 1024
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sockd;
    int counter;
    int fd;
    struct sockaddr_in fServer;
    char buf[MAXBUF];
    int status;
    if(argc<3)
    {
        printf("Incorrect data provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sockd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockd==-1)
    {
        printf("could not create socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fServer.sin_family=AF_INET;
    fServer.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
    fServer.sin_port=htons(SERVERPORT);
    status=connect(sockd, (struct sockaddr*)&fServer,
                sizeof(fServer));
    if(status==-1)
    {
        printf("could not connect to server\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    status=write(sockd, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]+1));
    if(status==-1)
    {
        printf("could not send file name to server\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    shutdown(sockd, SHUT_WR);

    fd=open(argv[2], O_WRONLY| O_CREAT| O_APPEND);
    if(fd==-1)
    {
        printf("could not open destination file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while((counter=read(sockd, buf, MAXBUF))>0)
    {
        write(fd, buf, counter);
    }
    if(counter==-1)
    {
        printf("file transfer is complete\n");
        exit(1);
    }
        printf("file transfer is complete\n");
    close(sockd);
    return 0;
}
```

I pass file name from  the same directory as server. I pass filename as agrc[2] parameter. Server oputput however is the following

```
socket is created
socket is waiting for connection
connection established, waiting for the file name
reading from the file
could not open the file
 error is detected: : No such file or directory
connection established, waiting for the file name
reading from the file
could not open the file
 error is detected: : No such file or directory
```

I entered the filename on my first attempt, then I enterd full path but still recieving the same message. So what is the problem? thanks in advance

Comment: Try printing the filename that you're trying to open.

Answer (score 1):

Client:

```
status=write(sockd, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]+1));
```

`strlen(argv[2]+1)` should be `strlen(argv[2])+1` if you want to include the \0.
also: you do not close your fd. `close(sockd);` should be `close(fd);`
Server:
`filename[i+1]='\0';` should be `filename[i]='\0';` if you are not sure you received the \0.
if you are sending 1 char, for example 'a', i would be 1 and your array would look like

```
filename[0] = 'a'
filename[i] = undefined
filename[i+1] = '\0'
```

Comment: Thanks, for that, however when I try to open the file textedit gives me error message filr cannot be opened

Comment: Probably cause argv[2] contains a wrong data for the reasons robin said

Comment: what's textedit? btw. you do not close the file descriptor close(sockd); should be close(fd);

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to your problem, but on the server side you should advance bufptr after write(), not before.

Also: TCP is a stream protocol; there is no guarantee that a write() on one end of a connection will be completely read by a single recv() on the other end.